# Unable to install visual studio 2019 community edition in windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

Unable to install visual studio 2019 community edition in windows 10. Tried out all know possibilities.Working on a project in Unreal engine.

Issue is installer in not opening and stuck...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out several possibilities, installing latest Windows 10 SDK
 (The Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0) for Windows 10, version 1903)
could resolve the issue. thanks for the support. Could see installer window and proceed with installation of Visual studio.